# Override class on unit test

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin

I want to make some testing on my code in my Android project. I have a class (A) that provides access to my database, and another class (B) that uses it. I created a test class for B (BTest), but I need to override class A so that when BTest calls methods from B which will call methods from A, return specific values instead of actually accessing my database. Is it possible for unit test?

```
object A{
    fun getValue(): String{
        return DB.getValue(); //here I access my database to retrieve the value
    }
}

object B{
    fun doStuff(): String{
        val value = A.INSTANCE.getValue()
        //process the value
        return processedValue
    }
}

class BTest{
    @Test
    fun testDoStuff(){
        Assert.isSame(B.INSTANCE.doStuff(), “result”) //at the moment this is accessing the database.
    }
}
```

So somehow have a new A class on my testing folder that when in testDoStuff() B calls A.INSTANCE.getValue() I can do something else instead of actually accessing the database.

Thanks!

Comment: You should do dependency injection, that at the simplest means passing A to B's constructor, instead of B directly accessing A. This way, in tests you could pass any subclass of A. (Also, `object class` is not valid syntax, but I guess it's an oversight)

Comment: Dependency injection could be an option, thanks. I was wondering if the testing api would have something to override for this kind of scenarios. (Fixed object class - sorry I was coming up with an example by remembering kotlin sintax by heart) :)